# reverse doubly linked list in c#

Tags: c#, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'am trying to reverse circular doubly linked list, which looks like this:
[image: It looks like this]

Here is my Node class:

```
       private class Node<T>
   {
       public T Data { get; set; }
       public Node<T> PreviousNode { get; set; }
       public Node<T> NextNode { get; set; }

       public Node(object data, Node<T> next, Node<T> previous)
       {
           Data = (T) data;
           PreviousNode = previous;
           NextNode = next;
       }
   }
```

And here is part of my Linked list class, here is my reverse funtion is stored:

```
 public class DoublyLinkedList<T> :IList<T>
{
    private Node<T> headerNode;
 public DoublyLinkedList()
{
        headerNode = new Node<T>(null, null, null);

        headerNode.NextNode     = headerNode;
        headerNode.PreviousNode = headerNode;
        Count = 0;
}

   public void Insert(int index, T item)
   {
        Node<T> node;

        if (index == Count)
            node = new Node<T>(item, headerNode, headerNode.PreviousNode);                                                                   
        else
        {
            Node<T> tmp = FindNodeAt(index); 

            node = new Node<T>(item, tmp, tmp.PreviousNode);
        }

        node.PreviousNode.NextNode = node; 
        node.NextNode.PreviousNode = node; 

        Count++;

    }
 public void Reverse()
    {
       Node<T> temp;
       for (Node<T> node = headerNode.NextNode; node != headerNode; node = node.NextNode)
       {

       }
    }
```

I completly stuck with this Reverse() function. Any help?

Comment: You could traverse the list swapping the next and previous nodes.

Comment: Do you want to reverse the current list or create a new list that's the reverse of the current list?

Comment: You could simply introduce `bool IsReversed` property which will change index numbering and enumeration for all methods.

Comment: Any particular reason you need to reverse it - as it is doubly linked surely all you need to do is decide whether you follow the NextNode or the PreviousNode links? But just swapping all NextNode & PreviousNode links would reverse the list.

Comment: @ChrisF I want to reverse the current list

Comment: Don't you need data to be of type `T`? The constructor should be `public Node(T data, Node<T> next, Node<T> previous)`. Also the `headerNode` initialization should be `headerNode=new Node<T>(default(T), null, null);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reverse the current list - then this should work :

```
public void Reverse()
{
   if (count < 2)
    return;

   Node<T> node = headerNode;
   do
   {
        Node<T> temp = node.NextNode;
        node.NextNode = node.PreviousNode;
        node.PreviousNode = temp;
        node = temp;
   }
   while (temp != headerNode)
}
```

The first lines check for empty or single element list. The main loop iterates through the list swapping the previous & next nodes, stopping when it gets back to the header node. The result is a reversed list.

Comment: That's what I talked about! Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The algorithm for reversing a linked list is very simple:

- Is the list empty or one element? If yes, then it is already reversed.
- Otherwise, create a new empty list. In a loop, remove the first item from the old list and add it to the start of the new list. Loop until the first list is empty.

So, break it down into smaller pieces. Can you write methods that (1) check if a list is empty (2) or one element (3) remove the first item from a non-empty list, (4) put an item onto the head of a list ?  If you can write those four methods then you can combine them together to write Reverse.

This is how you should be approaching your programming problems; programming is all about breaking complex problems down into simpler problems, solving the simpler problems, and combining the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than reverse the list why not write a couple of methods that get the "next" and "previous" node of the list depending on a direction flag that's passed in:

```
public Node Next(Node current, bool forward)
{
    return forward ? current.NextNode : current.PreviousNode;
}

public Node Previous(Node current, bool forward)
{
    return forward ? current.PreviousNode : current.NextNode;
}
```

You could replace `bool forward` by an enum with values `Forwards` & `Backwards` if that'd make the code easier to read.

Comment: This is great, thank you. But I need exactly the Reverse() method, because this is kind of a test assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody, I have found the solution.

```
 public void Reverse()
   {
       var currNode = headerNode;
       do
       {
           var temp = currNode.NextNode;
           currNode.NextNode = currNode.PreviousNode;
           currNode.PreviousNode = temp;
           currNode = currNode.PreviousNode;
       } 
       while (currNode != headerNode);
   }
```